# Redirect not working in cpanel & htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

I have set up a redirect in htaccess which supposedly redirects from mywebsite.com to targetsite.com. The htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN Redirects

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://targetsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]

# END redirects

RewriteOptions inherit

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Problem is that this configuration does not work at all! And mywebsite.com still brings me to mywebsite.com

Aside from the htaccess or cpanel level, are there any other underlying issues (DNS, nameserver) that might cause this redirect to fail?

Comment: A host name does not end with a slash.

Comment: tried updating but still does not work. does caching issue exist in htaccess files?

Comment: No, caching of the file itself should not be an issue. _"are there any other underlying issues (DNS, nameserver) that might cause this redirect to fail?"_ - are you sure the request for `mywebsite.com` reaches this server to begin with? And gets routed into the directory where this .htaccess is located?

Comment: the reason I came up with that conclusion is that my robots.txt file also does not reflect the changes made in cpanel. could also be the same reason why my redirects are not working.

Comment: Redirects to: Not Redirected and document root is in /public_html (which I think is the right directory) if there are any issues on these, let me know